# Front end date variable - SQL

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

My users enter parameters into an sql query from a front end system. I have successfully passed strings before, but I would like to pass a date variable now. My SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN P.SNAPSHOT_DATE = '{?startdate}' THEN P.MKT_VAL ELSE 0 END) 
  FROM P
```

The front end has some sql that defines what `startdate` is.

As I say, with strings, this works a dream. Unfortunately my compiler is expecting a date and so I get the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have tried surrounding my variable with cast and convert to no luck.

Comment: Just a hunch, but could it be that crystal-reports puts that variable in as a string? Then maybe in some format that can't be implicitly casted as a date? F.e. if MySql expects something like '2018-09-15', but that string is actually in a format like 'Wed, 18-15-09'.

Comment: In the front end (a program separate to Crystal Reports) I can specify the data type. Although I acknowledge this does not necessarily mean Crystal is smart enough to pick this up!

Comment: If you would know what format is used for the variable then you could use f.e. the [str_to_date](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp) function in the SQL.

Comment: Maybe one of the values is not strictly a date value and crashes when it tries to use it as a date.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your query, when you get the user input convert that input to a date type ie using SQL

```
  Set @userinput= select   CAST(@userinput as date)
```

On the front end try to limit the amount of manual inputing of data by the user,  by giving them the ability to select a date from a calendar rather than manually typing in the date, that should reduce errors I think. Let me know if the converting thing works! :)